# When in Settings Background the image selection freezes and quits

Tags: 18.04, settings, desktop-background

When I try to access setting the background through settings->background and then click the image, it freezes and then eventually quits. Anybody know of a way to get it to work?

Maybe the system is trying to open a program for browsing the directory where there might be a permissions issue or the program does not exist?

Thank you!!!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I installed tweaks and rebooted. Tweaks now seems to work. Before rebooting it had an xml file showing for the background image selection. Now it has the /usr/share/backgrounds directory files.

sudo apt-get install tweaks